# How to scrape data from web page using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-scraping

I want to get values from my html page.
I tried to get the same using HttpWebRequest but i am not able to do so far please help ?

```
    <div class="container">

        <div class="one-third column">
<ol start="181">
<li><a href="/lyrics/hindi-lyrics-of-Aaye%20Din%20Bahar%20Ke.html">Aaye Din Bahar Ke</a>
</li><li><a href="/lyrics/hindi-lyrics-of-Aayega%20Aane%20Wala.html">Aayega Aane Wala</a>
</li><li><a href="/lyrics/hindi-lyrics-of-Aayi%20Milan%20Ki%20Raat.html">Aayi Milan Ki Raat</a>

</li><li><a href="/lyrics/hindi-lyrics-of-Aiyyaa.html">Aiyyaa</a>
</li><li><a href="/lyrics/hindi-lyrics-of-Ajab%20Gazabb%20Love.html">Ajab Gazabb Love</a>

</li></ol>
    </div>

<div class="sixteen columns">

<hr>
More Pages: 
<a href="hindi-songs-starting-A.html">1</a> : <a href="hindi-songs-starting-A-page-2.html">2</a> : 3 : <a href="hindi-songs-starting-A-page-4.html">4</a> : <a href="hindi-songs-starting-A-page-5.html">5</a> : <a href="hindi-songs-starting-A-page-6.html">6</a> : 
        <hr>
<center>

<h4>Hindi Lyrics By Movie Title</h4>
<p>         
<a href="/lyrics/hindi-songs-starting-0.html">0-9</a>
<a href="/lyrics/hindi-songs-starting-A.html">A</a>
<a href="/lyrics/hindi-songs-starting-B.html">B</a>

<a href="/lyrics/hindi-songs-starting-W.html">W</a>
X
<a href="/lyrics/hindi-songs-starting-Y.html">Y</a>
<a href="/lyrics/hindi-songs-starting-Z.html">Z</a>
 | <a href="http://www.hindilyrics.net/songs/">Top Songs</a>
</p>
</center>

    </div>
```

this is my html i want to get all links

Comment: what you have tried. share your code(C#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can scrape we sit Using htmlagilitypack. you can download from here http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

```
string urls = "your web page";
        string result = string.Empty;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urls);
        request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5";

        using (var stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(new StringReader(result));

        var elements = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='one-third column']");
        foreach (HtmlNode item in elements)
        {
            var node1 = item.SelectNodes(".//li");
            foreach (HtmlNode li in node1)
            {
                var a = li.SelectSingleNode("//a").Attributes["href"].Value;//your link
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` class and it's `GetAsync()` method. HttpClient class comes with nice features for asynchronous downloading of websites. Or you can use `WebRequest` class - a very basic approach.